# Swift Core Data - DataModel Entity Relationships

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm still unsure whether I understand entity relationships. Just to confirm can I get someone to walk me through what I have created and confirm whether it is correct?

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqxRg.png)

So I'm creating a quiz app. This is my understanding of the above :

- Category Entity - (e.g. geography) has a many to one relationship with QuizName. A single category can have multiple QuizNames.
- A quizName (e.g. rivers in China) can have multiple Question entities. e.g. 'Which of one of these rivers are in China'
- A Question can then have 4 possibleAnswers from which the person can choose from.

Have I made the data model correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model looks good, but `Quiz` seems better than `QuizName`.

If `--->>` is a one-to-many relationship:

`Category --->> Quiz --->> Question`

A Question entity could either have 4 `String` properties that represent answers or if each answer has specific attributes than maybe an answer should be yet another entity.